# Why does braced-init-list behave differently in a function call versus a constructor invocation?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, c++14, list-initialization

Compiling the following code with clang 3.5.0 and gcc 4.9.1 yields an error at the last statement.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { Foo(int x, int y) { std::cout << "Foo(int = " << x << ", int = " << y << ")" << std::endl; } };

void bar(int x, int y) { std::cout << "bar(int = " << x << ", int = " << y << ")" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   Foo({}, {});   // Foo(int = 0, int = 0)
   Foo({1}, {2}); // Foo(int = 1, int = 2)
   Foo({1, 2});   // Foo(int = 1, int = 2)

   bar({}, {});   // bar(int = 0, int = 0)
   bar({1}, {2}); // bar(int = 1, int = 2)
   bar({1, 2});   // error: no matching function for call to 'bar'  <<< Why? <<<
}
```

Why is `Foo({1, 2})` okay while `bar({1, 2})` is not?

Particularly, it would be great to learn about the rationale.

Comment: My guess is, `Foo({1,2})` creates a temporary Foo object and calls the copy ctor.

Comment: The comment by @Borgleader is correct - with {1, 2} you can create a temporary Foo object, but only when Foo is expected. You cannot actually pass multiple parameters to function with that.

Comment: Huh, funny... interestingly `vec.insert(vec.back(), {...})` works just fine, contrary to your code (calls the `std::initializer_list` version). I just wrote that a few mins ago hoping the C++ committee was smart enough to think of that when they implemented initializer lists, so this will "just work", and it does indeed. Which is, truly, awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foo({1,2})` creates a temporary Foo object and calls the copy constructor.

See this modified example with copy constructor delete:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cb80746a8479799

It errors with:

```
main.cpp:6:5: note: candidate constructor has been explicitly deleted
    Foo(const Foo& f) = delete;
```

Comment: But wasn't a copy constructor implicitly generated in the original example ? Why delete it and cause another reason not to compile ? This does not exaplain why `bar` cannot be called; and it's all about the arguments of bar, see this [way of fixing compilation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b8f6fee6244c251)

Comment: @NorahAttkins You missed the point. The point was, the initializer list isn't passing the 2 ints to the constructor (which the OP assumed, and wondered why it wouldn't work in a function call that also takes 2 ints), it's generating a temporary object and calling the copy constructor. Deleting it showed that the copy constructor was being called.

Comment: No it didn't; Watch this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7314848093d2987a) If I remove the call to `Foo({1, 2})` the program still fails to compile when calling `bar` without ever mentioning anything about deleted copy constructors. The call to `bar` never created a temporary `Foo` object

Comment: @NorahAttkins Re-read what I said, OP's reasonable assumption was that the initializer list was compatible with a signature taking two ints, when in reality in the case of the Foo object it was creating a temporary, which meant that he shouldn't expect the call to bar to succeed. Why the call to bar fails *is a different matter*.

Comment: Yes, you are right; silly of me. Thanks for schooling me on `initializer_list` types .... em I should say "no types"

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
bar({1, 2});
```

actually passes in the `bar` function, a temporary object of type

```
<brace-enclosed initializer list> // it's made clear in the comments that brace initializers have no type
```

and there is no way to convert this temporary object to the type of the first argument which is an `int`. Thus the [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b7e810380ed58fa)

> cannot convert `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `int` for argument `1` to

```
void bar(int, int)
```

Comment: No, that is not correct. A braced-init-list does not have a type.

Comment: @NorahAttkins [A braced initializer has no type](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU&list=UUMlGfpWw-RUdWX_JbLCukXg#t=1792)

Comment: Yes. What you are showing results from a special (idiotic) rule introduced precisely for this case.

Comment: @Borgleader That's a bit confusing. Doesn't the program still fail when calling `bar` due to type mismatch ? (I'll watch the video soon) To my understanding, `no type` resembles "lambdas have no type" meaning they have a type which we don't know

Comment: @NorahAttkins Except lambdas have a type, but it's anonymous.